# Update multiple rows with loop not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have simple problem in my project. I want to update data in db.
The sku codes sent with ajax. Like this A-1, A-2, A-3

I tried:

```
$sku2 = $request['sku'];
$sku = explode(',', $sku2);
foreach ($sku as $key => $value){
     $content = ProductNew::where('sku', $value)->update(['price' => 
     $price]);
}
```

But it updated only first record (A-1)
Where is the problem?

This is full fuction

```
    public function setdiscount(Request $request)
    {
    $discount = Discount::where('id', $request['id'])->first();
    $d_price = $discount['price'];
    $d_type = $discount['type'];
    $price = 17;
    $sku2 = $request['sku'];
    $sku = explode(',', $sku2);
    foreach ($sku as $key => $value){
        ProductNew::whereIn('sku', $sku)->update(['price' => $price]);
    }



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using wherein() along with update() to update multiple records:

```
$sku2 = $request['sku'];
$sku = explode(',', $sku2);

$sku = array_map('trim', $sku);

ProductNew::whereIn('sku', $sku)->update(['price' => $price]);
```

Comment: what's inside of $sku? is this an array with more than one value? check it: dd($sku);

Comment: array:5 [
  0 => "NHD-F070"
  1 => " NHD-F070-1"
  2 => " NHD-F070-2"
  3 => " NHD-F070-3"
  4 => " NHD-F070-4"
]

Comment: it seems to be no problem with this code, the issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: I notice there is space in other elements in your array. That is the issue. Look at this  " NHD-F070-2" (there is a space at the start).

Comment: i added full function where the problem?

Comment: Yes you are right! I had not seen that thank you a lot

Comment: Trim every value of array using array_map $sku = array_map('trim', $sku); and try again. I updated my answer.